# Quantum Derivation of wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Because of my limited knowledge of quantum mechanics I have a question.

I know about the wave function describing the uncertainty of two 'dependent' properties at the quantum level.

If you try to measure one of the properties the more you are uncertain of the other and vice versa.

My question is this how is the wave function of this uncertainty derived.

Intuitively it cannot be done empirically because of the uncertainty.

You cannot get results and then use those results to formulate a function because of the uncertainty of the results if indeed it is uncertain.

So just exactly how do you derive the wavefunction and confirm it to describe the associated behaviour of the system.

Answer (score 1):

> I know about the wave function describing the uncertainty of two
>   'dependent' properties at the quantum level.

Not really. The wave function $\psi(r)$ is obtained by solving the Schrödinger equation (SE) of the quantum system at hand. The wave function contains all the information of the quantum system, information that is obtained from it by treating $\psi(r)$ with relevant *quantum operators* (e.g. the momentum operator).

For example in one dimension $x$, the quantum *momentum operator* is:

$$\text{p}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

In its most condensed form the (time independent) SE is:

$$\text{H}\psi(r)=E\psi(r)$$

where $\text{H}$ is the Hamiltonian operator and $E$ is the total energy of the quantum system at hand.

The square of modulus of the wave function, $|\psi(r)|^2$, gives us the *probability density* $P(r)$ of the quantum system at hand.

The uncertainty relations arise from the fact that the operators of some canonical properties, e.g. *position and momentum*, [do not commute](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node188.html). For the latter pair this results in the famous uncertainty relation:

$$\sigma_x \sigma_p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The square of the wavefunction is a probability density. It describes how probable the outcome of an experiment is. Thus, as you implied, you cannot know empirically if your wavefunction is the right one with the results of an experiment. However, if you repeat the experiment many times, you constrain your wavefunction.  Intuitively, if you measure 8 times out of 10 that the particle is within 1 meter  of a given object, then it is very improbable that the "true" wavefunction is most probable at 10 meters.  If you repeat the experiment an infinite amount of time, you can be certain that only one wavefunction describes your results.

If you want to think about theoretically, the uncertainty of the measurements is built in the theory. Measurable quantities such as position, momentum and spin are represented as operators (which you can think as matrices if you're familiar with that). For any given state, you can represent it in a "nice" basis of eigenvectors of the operator that you are interested in, say position. Then the probabilities of each outcome of a measurement are given by the coefficients multiplying your eigenvectors in your state decomposition.

Comment: I have a further question. Is there a fixed number of possible quantum systems and there's respective wave functions that describe their behaviour which pose a limit on universal systems. In Another way can the universe be described by a finite use of a fixed number of quantum systems applied to sum total universe?